# Substitute Backslash for Forward slash in last command

Tags: bash, cygwin, regex

I've copied the command `cd C:\foo\bar\` from PowerShell to Cygwin and sillily expected it to execute. I'm now trying to run a substitution to replace all the `\` with `/`:

```
$ !!:gs/\\/\/
bash: :gs/\\/\/: substitution failed
```

Not sure why I'm getting substitution failed.

I also tried:

```
$ !!:gs/\\/q
```

Just to see if the replace was the problem. It's not. Now I'm curious!

Why am I getting "substitution failed"?

Comment: I have no cygwin at hand right now, but I thought, that Windows paths are working... have you tried to singe-quote the argument? I.e. `cd 'C:\foo\bar'`

Comment: @mpy This actually works too! Didn't know I wasn't stuck with substitution.

Comment: "Would be open to an answer using zsh as well". Your original `!!:gs/\\/\/` does work in zsh…

Comment: @TannerFaulkner `fc  -s '\'='/' -1` works under the Ubuntu LTS default bash. Let me know if it works under Cygwin too. I posted more words in the answer.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski `!!:gs/\\/\/` works on my zsh 5.0.2 too.

Comment: i think the general bash behavior here is that the backslashes are processed as escapes before the substitution happens in `!!:gs/\\/\//`.  @Hastur 's `fc -s '\'='/' -1` gets the expected behavior.  this might be a bug in bash.

Comment: @quixotic thanks for the feedback. I've tried after a `shopt -s histverify` those commands `echo C:\Foo\Bar` then `!!:s|C|D| {1,2}A`, enter, obtaining as verified expansion `echo D:\Foo\Bar {1,2}A` then enter again and `D:FooBar 1A 2A`. So it seems to be a problem in the history expansion processed before of the Brace expansion, so [first of all](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/intro#order)...

Answer (score 6):

a forward slash is also the delimiter of your substitute command, so you must escape it as the replacement string so as not to end the substitution early

```
!!:gs/\\/\//
```

or more plainly as suggested in the comments, by using something besides slash as the delimiter

```
!!:gs|\\|/|
```

But this only seems to work in `tcsh` (the shell commonly assigned where I am),  I can't get the command to work in `bash` as it seems escaping doesn't work on the first argument of `:s`

Comment: No joy :( Same error https://i.imgur.com/QFQR0xF.png

Comment: Just a remark: `!!:gs|\\|/` might be a little bit more readable.

Comment: I could not get it to work in bash.  The first arg of `:s` doen't seem to be a real regex

Comment: This is not working

Answer (score 5):

#### Short answer: the builtin [`fc` (fix command)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Builtins.html#Bash-History-Builtins) of bash

[`fc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Builtins.html#Bash-History-Builtins) is the command, *built-in* in the bash shell, made to edit & re-execute commands of the history.
It is [present on CygWin too](http://www.softpanorama.org/Utilities/fc.shtml) and it works on all the Linux distributions on which I tested:

```
fc  -s '\'='/' -1
```

**Some explanations**

- `fc` is the bash [*built-in* command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Builtins.html#Bash-History-Builtins) to list or edit and re-execute commands from the history list.
- `-1` will take the last command in the history. Note that even `!!` is defined (read from `man bash`) as

  > `!!     Refer to the previous command.  This is a synonym for`**!-1**'.
- `-s` to substitute a pattern with another. This time from `help fc` (built-in command so `help`):

  > With the `fc -s [pat=rep ...] [command]' format, COMMAND is
  >   re-executed after the substitution OLD=NEW is performed.

  <sup>Ok they mean `pat=rep` instead of `OLD=NEW` ...</sup>
- The patterns will be read by the shell so we have to protect them with quote: `'\'` and `'/'`.

#### Some words more about why you are getting "substitution failed"

It seems that for the `s` [modifier](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Modifiers.html#Modifiers) is not (yet) implemented the substitution of the backslash character `\`, that is the escape one. To be sure we should see the code, for example, of the gnu version of the bash history expansion (but there was the above command to obtain what you were trying to do...so I *take it lazy*....).

**Some notes:**

1. We are lead to think that it will work each RegEx we find working with `sed`, but it is not guaranteed. The backslash is the escape character of the expansion and the problem is here. Moreover the behaviour of the expansion is related with the `shopt` options, so we should start to see case by case...
2. When you paste the string `cd C:\Foo\Bar` in your bash shell it will be expanded and it will appear for the interpreter as `cd C:FooBar`; in this form it will be stored in the `$_` internal variable too.
   If you instead pasted `cd "C:\Foo\Bar"` or `cd 'C:\Foo\Bar'` in the `$_`
   variable you should find `C:\Foo\Bar`.
   Since the History expansion is performed immediately after a complete line is read, before the shell breaks it into words, you may be tempted to start to use it with some *bashism* more or less plain, e.g., with some derivation from (maybe adding `:p` or `:q`, `""`, parsing and so on...)

   ```
   !!:0 ${_//\\/\/}
   ```

   **This is the moment to remember that it is not safe** to start **to play with path and *filenames***, especially if they come from the windows clipboard (read in general the page [**Why *not* parse `ls`?**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls), it is essentially related with the possibility to use tab, spaces and newlines as correct characters for the file names and the directory ones...).
   Moreover when you **paste a text captured with the mouse**, you may paste a leading space too. This may avoid that your command will finish in the history (it depends from the shell options...). If so your following `!!` will be a not controlled command... (see an example in [another answer](https://superuser.com/a/776767/257269)). **This is a unneeded tangible risk**.

**Conclusion**

> **History expansions** introduce words from the history list into the input stream, **making it easy** to repeat commands, insert the arguments to a previous command into the current input line, or fix errors in previous commands quickly.

If it is not easy I start to think we are doing something wrong `;-)`

---

**Ad nauseam: a little experiment**

I've enabled `histverify` in the shell then...

```
shopt -s histverify
echo C:\Foo\Bar
!!:s|C|D| {1,2}A
```

then I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and as *verified* expansion I find

```
echo D:\Foo\Bar {1,2}A
```

then I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again and it echoes

```
D:FooBar 1A 2A
```

This seems to indicate that the `substitution failed` is generated in the history expansion processed before of the *Brace expansion*, so [first of all](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/intro#order), and it seems to confirm that the `s` history modifier didn't (yet) process the substitution of the `\` character as a real regex...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed` to substitute and execute the result.

There are several possible variants for such a command, but on my bash only this one worked:

```
A=$(echo "!!\\" | sed 's,\\,/,g');eval $A
```

The `\\` is added to the `!!` is in case the last command terminated with a
backslash. Without it, the shell will get confused and ask for the continuation
of the line.

You could also add this as a bash function in the file `~/.bashrc` :

```
function slash {
   A=$(history | tail -n 2 | head -n 1 | cut -c 8- | sed 's,\\,/,g')
   eval $A
}
```

Here is how this works on my Bash on Windows :

[image: bash]

To explain how the `A=` command assigns the right value to the shell variable `A`:

- `tail` takes the last two lines from the command history, which gives the
  lines of `cd \mnt\c` followed by `slash` itself.
  The part of `history | tail -n 2` may also be written as `history 2`.
- `head` take the first line which is `cd \mnt\c`
- `cut` cuts out the line-number supplied by `history`
- `sed` replaces all anti-slashes by slashes
- `eval` executes the contents of the variable `A`

Comment: Hi Harry. Sorry to say that on my GNU  bash version 4.3.11(1)  the `A=$(echo "!!\\" | sed 's,\\,/,g');eval $A` doesn't work when the command terminated with a backslash. You are forced to add a space, e.g. to `C:\Foo\Bar\ ` else, as you said, the shell will wait for the continuation of the line. You can also press enter twice. In the first case you obtain `C:/Foo/Bar /` (with a space before the `/`; in the second it will generate an error.  The function works fine.

Comment: I wrote the function because (1) It's much easier to use, and (2) The one-liner seemed too implementation-dependent.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can do this. You need to copy/past again.

The issue is not related to slash beeing also the substitute command separator, since substitute command accept any separator. The issue is about the back-slashes to be substituted, which have been already treated as simple useless escapements of character on their right.

Hence, when you call the substitute command, backslash is already vanished from the source. Just try to re-call the command as is (`!!`). Instead of printing the exact same command including `c:\foo`, it will execute the command minus already-processed backslashes which result in `c:foo`.

And obviously you can not find nor replace a missing character. Trying to do so will fire an error.

Comment: Well. That is finally wrong since this test actually works: `echo c:\Foo` followed by `!!:gs,F,\\f,`. But Substituting the backslash escape itself appears to be a pain.